# Chamar entidade EF por nome e realizar pesquisa dinamicamente

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Na aplicação *WindowsForm* que estou desenvolvendo, pretendo criar apenas um `form` padrão para listagem dos registros que será chamado através do menu de cadastros do sistema.

Esse `form` de listagem, além dos botões de incluir, editar e excluir do registro selecionado na `gridview`, terá um painel para que o usuário possa montar sua expressão de pesquisa nos registros, que será composta de COLUNA (`combobox`) + OPERADOR (maior,menor,diferente, etc) e VALOR, exemplo DATA MAIOR QUE 01/01/2015.

Na minha aplicação eu tenho 3 camadas, Aplicação, Negócio e Dados.

As dúvidas são as seguintes em relação a como estruturar isso usando [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework):

1. Como passar para o `form` de listagem a minha classe mapeada EF
   (tabela) uma fez que poderá ser envidado qualquer uma, exemplo 
   produtos, fornecedores, bancos etc.
2. Passado a classe EF para o `form` de pesquisa, como ir a minha
   camada de negócio e executar o método de listar? imagino que em cada
   objeto de negócio teria que ter uma método de listar com um nome
   padrão?
3. Para criar o painel de pesquisa, que após o usuário preencher será
   executado e apresentado no `gridview`, como posso popular o
   `combobox` que a relação de colunas da tabela?
4. Como posso montar a pesquisa de forma dinâmica pegando COLUNA +
   OPERADOR + VALOR?

Comment: Felipe, sua pergunta realmente parece ampla demais. Sugiro postar cada dúvida separadamente, incluindo suas tentativas para resolver cada problema.

Comment: Realmente a pergunta é muito ampla, só seria possível responder com uma solução praticamente pronta pra você utilizar. Tente implementar do seu jeito, e faça perguntas individuais para cada dúvida que for surgindo.